# problem migrating my drupal site PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user

Tags: database, migrations

I have just loaded my drupal 7.32 site to JustHost from my pc (running xampp) copied the files across, and exported and imported the database to JustHost cpanel, i browse onto the website and I get the error message below. I have triple checked my database name and username of the database and password and they are correctly specified in my settings.php file. My database was called 'school2' on the pc, but I'm not sure that will affect anything.

I get this error message:-

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'caerleon_prim'@'localhost' to database 'caerleon_prim' in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /home4/caerleon/public_html/includes/lock.inc).

Can anyone help?

Comment: "but I'm not sure that will affect anything." Yes, it will, you have to set database name, user and password correctly. All three are needed. Plus, some hosting companies use different "machine names" for databases, and different in panel. You need to ask **them** what exactly you should put as name, user and password to access your DB.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With JustHost you need to assign the user to the database from the Database Maintenance drop down page. Instructions are on their site too. I did this, and it fixed my problem.